# How can I find the index of an array that has objects in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, multidimensional-array, iterator

I have an array of objects and I want to find which element in the array has a particular attribute equal to a value, specifically which element in this array has an object that has `:parent_id` equal to `55`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To find the index:

```
 array.index{ |item| item.parent_id == 55 }
```

To find the item:

```
array.find{ |item| item.parent_id == 55 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 array.collect{|a| a[:parent_id]==55 ? a : nil}.compact!
```

should do the Job. First collect all elements matching your criteria in a new array, than remove false positives (nil) elements.

Comment: If you just use select or find_all the compact statement isn't needed, so it should be a little faster.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Enumerable#select  [Docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-select)

```
results = my_array.select do |item|
  item[:parent_id] == 55
end
```